# Android notificiations not being displayed

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have some code set up for the Status Notification, nothing is wrong with the code according to eclipse. However the code wont run when I start it up.  Well It bypasses the notification and goes straight to the main activity. Why is my code skipping the notifications?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NoteMe extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");
    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.something.MainActivity");

    PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "STOP LOOK LISTEN!", System.currentTimeMillis());

    CharSequence message = "This is your alert, courtesy of the AlarmManager";
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, message, message, detailsIntent);
    notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };
    nm.notify(notifID, notif);
    finish();
}

}
```

Followed by Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.something"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity android:name=".NoteMe" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.something.NoteMe" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And logcat!
--Actually there is nothing in logcat (Strange)

Comment: Are you able to successfully send notifications from your main activity? As in, it's just not working in this activity?

Comment: I can send "Toast" messages if that counts. I have yet to try to send a big notification yet.

Comment: Have you put a toast in the onCreate of this activity to make sure that it is being called at all?

Comment: Are you starting this activity with an Intent? How is it being called?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent("com.example.something.MainActivity");

  PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest, if you remove the `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` from the intent filter of your MainActivity and put it in the intent filter of your NoteMe activity, that activity should run on launch instead of the other. You just need to launch MainActivity from your NoteMe activity, right before you call `finish()`.

Comment: It is throwing a null pointer exception according to logcat (Which just started working O.o)

Comment: The NoteMe activity throws a NullPointerException when it runs? Does the notification ever show up?

Comment: Yes the NoteMe activity throws the exception.The notification never shows up and the mainactivity itself flashes then instantly crashes.

Comment: If the MainActivity starts running shouldn't NoteMe already be gone?

Comment: Yeah but its just flat out ignoring the NoteMe, I tried flip flopping the Intent Filters in the Manifest but got no where with it. Would not launch anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate()` method is missing `setContentView()`.  This should be called after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.  This tells Android which XML layout you would like to associate with the `Activity`.